# WPF C# set trigger property in control by code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, wpf-controls, contentcontrol

```
<ContentControl Width="130"
                Height="130"
                Canvas.Top="60"
                Canvas.Left="50"
                ***Selector.IsSelected="True"***
                Style="{StaticResource DesignerItemStyle}">
```

I would like to set property `Selector.IsSelected` to `ContentControl` by using code behind. But I don't know how to do it. Please help me and give me some example.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to set an attached dependency property in code you do this

```
        ContentControl x;
        //To set the value
        x.SetValue(Selector.IsSelectedProperty, true);

        //To Clear the value
        x.ClearValue(Selector.IsSelectedProperty);

        //Set using the static function on Selector
        Selector.SetIsSelected(x, true);
```

Comment: thanks so much, work perfect...

Comment: @nsnara If it works for you.. do you mind accepting it as an answer

Answer (score 2):

For accessing a control in Code-behind you need first provide it a name -

```
<ContentControl 
    x:Name=""ContentControl1"
    Width="130" 
    Height="130" 
    Canvas.Top="60" 
    Canvas.Left="50" 
    ***Selector.IsSelected="True"*** 
    Style="{StaticResource DesignerItemStyle}">
```

and then you can access it in code and set the value as mentioned in other answer -

```
ContentControl1.SetValue(Selector.IsSelectedProperty, true);
```

Apart from this it would be a good idea to look at creating a property in code-behind or ViewModel(MVVM) and bind that directly to your control like this -

```
<ContentControl 
    Width="130" 
    Height="130" 
    Canvas.Top="60" 
    Canvas.Left="50" 
    Selector.IsSelected="{Binding IsSelectedBoolProperty, Mode=OneWay}"
    Style="{StaticResource DesignerItemStyle}">
```

This techniques will be very useful in case you have a lot of controls in your window and I would suggest you to look at implementing MVVM in your application to avoind doing these kind of things in code-behind.